# Obtaining last occurance of row on MySQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have the following tables in my Database:

**USERS**

```
+-------+-------------------------------------+
|   id  |                name                 |
+-------+-------------------------------------+
|   1   | Johnny Appleseed                    |
|   2   | Pete Jones                          |
|   3   | John Doe                            |
|   4   | Jane Plick                          |
+-------+-------------------------------------+
```

**REPORTS**

```
+-------+-------+-----------------------------+
|   id  | owner | title                       |
+-------+-------+-----------------------------+
|   1   | 1     | Weekly report #86           |
|   2   | 1     | Weekly report #87           |
|   3   | 1     | Weekly report #88           |
|   4   | 2     | Weekly report #1            |
|   5   | 3     | Weekly report #33           |
|   6   | 3     | Weekly report #34           |
+-------+-------------------------------------+
```

What I need to do is GROUP the results by first name, so that the list itself is alphabetical order, but I need the LAST occurrence of the row matching the user's id.

The "owner" column of the REPORTS table matches the "id" column of the USERS table.

My desired results look like:

```
Jane Plick       |     
John Doe         | Weekly Report #34
Johnny Appleseed | Weekly Report #88
Pete Jones       | Weekly Report #1
```

My current query ALMOST works, however it only shows the FIRST weekly report for that user, not the last.

```
SELECT * FROM users AS a LEFT JOIN ppp_reports AS b ON a.id=b.owner WHERE a.active=1 GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY a.firstname ASC
```

I have tried a lot of different variations, but I'm always left with the FIRST row from the REPORTS table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: that's standard mysql behavior when you're doing a `group by`. it'll pick the first/earliest values from matching record to fill in all the fields requested in the group. this is basically a "top n per group", where the top is "most recent" and n=1.

Comment: Are you assuming that the highest number value for `id` in the `reports` table is the most recent, or do you have any additional field (like a timestamp) that authoritatively determines the age of the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case where all reports are named "Weekly report #X", you can try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, MAX(b.title)
  FROM users AS a
  LEFT JOIN ppp_reports AS b ON a.id=b.owner
 WHERE a.active=1
 GROUP BY a.id, a.name
 ORDER BY a.name ASC
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/137ea/5).

If the reports may have other names, you'll have to find another way to discriminate the last report from the others.

Comment: This worked out well. As the ID of the ppp_reports table will always increment, the last report matching the user ID will always be the newest. So instead of MAX(b.title) I did MAX(b.id) and it's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your reports ID are numbered by date, i.e report ID 2 is always after report ID 1, these two queries should work:

```
select t.id, t.name, r.title from 
  (select u.id, u.name, max(r.id) as report_id
    from users u
    left join reports r on r.owner = u.id
    group by u.id, u.name) as t
    left join reports r on t.report_id = r.id;
```

OR

```
select u.id, u.name, r.title from
  users u 
  left join 
  (select r.owner, max(r.id) as report_id
    from reports r 
    group by r.owner) as latest_report on u.id = latest_report.owner
  left join reports r on latest_report.report_id = r.id;
```

The idea is that you need to identify the correct report, by user ID, and then join the reports table back to that to get the correct name for the report.

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb8ec/1)